Large deviations for stochastic processes and lack of lower semicontinuity
$\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$Let $(X^\eps_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ be a family of stochastic processes, say reasonable diffusions with generator $A^\eps$ and path measure $R^\eps$ on $\omega\in\Omega=C([0,1];\mathbb R^d)$.
A classical approach in order to investigate large deviations of $R^\eps$ is to look at the sequence of Hamiltonians
$$
H^\eps\phi=\eps e^{-\phi/\eps}A^\eps e^{\phi/\eps}.
$$
Assuming convergence (in some sense and for a sufficiently large class of test-functions $\phi\in(\dots))$
$$
\lim\limits_{\eps\to 0}H^\eps\phi(x)=H^\phi(x)=H(x,\nabla\phi(x))
$$
for some limiting Hamiltonian $H$, and assuming that one has the variational representation
$$
H(x,p)=\sup\limits_{q}\left\{p\cdot q- L(x,q)\right\}
$$
for a well-behaved Lagrangian $L(x,q)$, one usually expects that the LDP
$$
R^\eps\asymp\exp\left(-\frac 1\eps I(\omega)\right)
\qquad\text{as }\eps\to 0
$$
holds with rate function
$$
I(\omega)=I_0(\omega_0)+\int_0^1 L(\omega_t,\dot\omega_t) dt.
$$
Here $I_0(\omega_0)$ simply encodes the LDP for the initial distribution $X_0^\eps\sim\rho^\eps_0$, the challenge is usually to retrieve the tractable expression $\int_0^1 L(\dots)$ for the dynamical part.
As far as I can see the classical arguments go through:

the generation of the evolution semi-groups $\eps\log\mathbb E_x e^{\phi(X^\eps_t)} =V^\eps(t)\phi\to V(t)\phi$ solving the associated Hamilton–Jacobi–(Bellmann) equations $\frac d{dt} V^\eps(t)\phi=H^\eps V^\eps(t)\phi$ and $\frac d{dt} V(t)\phi=H V(t)\phi$
Varadhan–Bryc type arguments
Hopf–Lax formulas from control theory to compute effectively the rate function as a dynamical Lagrangian minimization instead of abstract supremum over discrete-time slicings, see for example the book [1] by Feng and Kurtz.

All of this however stronly requires the Lagrangian $(x,q)\mapsto L(x,q)$ to be jointly lower semicontinuous, and relies on $H,H^\eps$ generating "nice" evolution semigroups $V(t),V^\eps(t)$.

Question can anyone give me any hint as to what I should do when no "good" variational representation is available? More precisely, in
my application (that I prefer not to discuss here for the sake of
brevity) I still have that $H(x,\cdot)$ and $L(x,\cdot)$ are convex
conjugate of one another for any fixed $x$, but I do not have joint
lower-semicontinuity (the $x$-dependence is badly not l.s.c.).

A typical example in dimension 1 might be when the generator $A$ is $a\partial_{xx}$ for $x<0$ and $b\partial_{xx}$ for $x>0$, with discontinuity $a\neq b$ across $x=0$, and the $\eps$ parameter is just used to slow-down time $A^\eps=\eps A$.
Formally the Lagrangian is just $L(x,q)=\frac{1}{a}|q|^2$ if $x<0$ and $L(x,q)=\frac 1b|q|^2$ if $x>0$. I am not a probabilist and I am not too sure this example is well-defined because I am not really specifying what the process should do when crossing $x=0$. Maybe I don't need to, and in simpler terms I wonder about a Schilder-like theorem for the SDE
$$
dX_t=\eps \left(a\mathbf{1}(X_t<0)+b\mathbf{1}(X_t\geq 0)\right) dB_t.
$$
I hope you get the picture.

[1] Feng, J., & Kurtz, T. G. (2006). Large deviations for stochastic processes (No. 131). American Mathematical Society.
